# 1-indexing to 0-indexing in grep/sed/awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep, tr

I'm parsing a template using linux command line using pipes which has some 1-indexed pseudo-variables, I need 0-indexing. Bascially:

```
...{1}...{7}...
```

to become

```
...{0}...{6}...
```

I'd like to use one of `grep`, `sed` or `awk` in this order of preference. I guess `grep` can't do that but I'm not sure. Is such arithmetic operation even possible using any of these?

- numbers used in the file are in range `0-9`, so ignore problems like `23` becoming `12`
- no other numbers in the file, so you can even ignore the `{}`
- I can do that using python, ruby, whatever but I prefer not to so stick to standard command line utils
- other commend line utils usable with pipes with regex that I don't know are fine too

**EDIT**: Reworded first bullet point to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input allows it, you may be able to get away with simply:

```
tr 123456789 012345678
```

Note that this will replace all instances of any digit, so may not be suitable.  (For example, `12` becomes `01`.  It's not clear from the question if you have to deal with 2 digit values.)

If you do need to handle multi-digit numbers, you could do:

```
perl -pe 's/\{(\d+)\}/sprintf( "{%d}", $1-1)/ge'
```

Comment: ;) it;s quite clear, I guess: `numbers are in range 0-9`, didn't think of tr, this works and is amazingly simple, will wait for other answers though, I'll probably have a hard time picking the right answer, there are already two correct ways, and there might be others

Comment: Yes, I suppose you did clarify!

Comment: not me, just the opposite, whoever downvoted shoud be ashamed of themselves ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<={)\d+(?=})/$&-1/ge' file.txt
```

If you are sure you can ignore `{...}`, then use

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$&-1/ge' file.txt
```

And if index is always just one-digit number, then go with shorter one

```
perl -pe 's/\d/$&-1/ge' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks Ωmega, your answer works too, only choosing the other as for this very specific problem tr is more readable

Answer (score 1):

With gawk version 4, you can write:

```
gawk '
    {
        n = split($0, a, /[0-9]/, seps)
        for (i=1; i<n; i++)
            printf("%s%d", a[i], seps[i]-1)
        print a[n]
    }
'
```

Older awks can use

```
awk '
    {
        while (match(substr($0,idx+1), /[0-9]/)) {
            idx += RSTART
            $0 = substr($0,1, idx-1) (substr($0,idx,1) - 1) substr($0,idx+1)
        }
        print 
    }
'
```

Both less elegant than the Perl one-liners.